# Relation between application .dll files and system installed .dll/.sys files (specifically, FTDI drivers)

Tags: dll, kernel, drivers, sys, ftdi

I'm working on a project which uses the [D2XX drivers](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/CDM/CDM%20v2.12.24%20WHQL%20Certified.zip) from [FTDI chip](http://www.ftdichip.com/).

We are delivering the ftd2xx.dll file as part of our application. As far as I understand, the other files (e.g. ftdibus.sys) are installed on the system (at least for Windows) where the application runs. Linux is also a target for us, but let's ignore that for simplicity now.

My question is regarding the relation between these files? If, for example, I upgrade the ftd2xx.dll file delivered with our application, will users have to install the newest drivers? What if they do not?

In addition to the specific FTDI drivers, any general source of information on this area is also very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work on a project that made use of FTDI's D2XX library.

There is no tight coupling between the exact version of ftd2xx.dll and ftdibus.sys. I believe the interface between ftd2xx.dll and the kernel mode driver is version independent at the basic feature level (at least since version 2.04.06 or so). There is even functions in the DLL to query DLL and driver versions respectively.

Thus, it can happen that they are 'out of sync'. I.e. ftd2xx.dll could be one from a more recent release than ftdibys.sys or vice versa. That is not a problem as such.

You are of course in complete control of the ftd2xx.dll version, but how does the driver package get installed? Is it installed as part of your application, or do you rely on the user obtaining the driver from another source? If your application has an installer, it could be an option to include FTDI's driver package in the installation. Thereby you will know which driver version is available.

What can be really tricky (and what has caused me headaches) is if there are other devices on the PC that use FTDI's chip. If such a device is supplied with media containing an older version of the driver and the user chooses to install this driver, it will simply overwrite any existing version of the driver (e.g. the version that your installer provided). This is a potential cause of regression, because FTDI has resolved a lot of bugs in the driver over the years.

If I were you, I would check the driver version at runtime and compare it to a version that is known to work (the version that you tested your application with). If the driver is older, suggest the user to upgrade it. Otherwise I would assume it is compatible.